# Ungraded Visual Studio 2022 - Debugging Error

Tags: debugging, upgrade, visual-studio-2022

I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2022.
When running a project (developed in VS 2019)  I get the following error/warning message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc55M.png)
You are debugging a Release build for APP_Name.exe. Using Just My Code with Releasae builds using compiler optimizations results in a degraded debugging experiance(e.g. breakpoints will not be hit)

Since I am fairly new to C#, I am lost as to what to do. The only "solution" I found online was to disable "Just My Code", but that seems to not be able to debug correctly.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please setting the configuration to Debug in the Configuration Manger window.
[image]